# Cannot use JQuery to remove contents of a search textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

On my screen I search for a contract and when I select it I get the associated data for the contract.
Once I have selected a contract, I want the contract title to render elsewhere further down the page. I can do that, but the contract title is also rendered in the search text box, and I do not want that.
So in my code I have;

```
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <span style="margin-right: 10px;">Find a Contract</span>
        <span style="margin-right: 50px;">
            <input type="search" id="searchtermContract" class="contractTitle"
                   data-msurvey-autocomplete="@Url.Action("Contract", "Autocomplete")"
                   data-msurvey-autocomplete-update-id="#ContractId"
                   data-msurvey-autocomplete-update-label="#ContractTitle1" 
                   data-msurvey-populate-search-textbox-flag="N"/>
        </span>
        <input type="button" id="ResetContract" value="Reset"
               style="margin-left: -40px;"
               class="btn-mulalley btn-xs reset"
               data-msurvey-reset-field="#searchtermContract"
               data-msurvey-reset-id="#ContractId" />
        <input type="hidden" id="ContractId" name="ContractId" />
        <input type="hidden" id="ContractTitle1" name="ContractTitle1" />
    </div>
</div>
<div id="propertiesForContract">

</div>
```

In my javascript I have

```
var getPropertiesForContract = function (contractId) {
    var url = GetHiddenField("msurvey-get-properties-for-contract-url").replace(/__ID__/, contractId);
    $('#propertiesForContract').load(url);
    // TODO this line is not working
    $("#searchtermContract").val("");
};
```

And in developer tools for IE, it shows that the searchtermContract does not have a value, yet the selected contract still get displayed. Why is this?

```
<input class="contractTitle ui-autocomplete-input" id="searchtermContract" type="search" data-msurvey-autocomplete-update-label="#ContractTitle1" data-msurvey-autocomplete-update-id="#ContractId" data-msurvey-autocomplete="/(S(jdfx1zrfoqjcrsyb0ltueuyp))/Autocomplete/Contract" data-msurvey-populate-search-textbox-flag="N" autocomplete="off">
```

Comment: What happens if you enter `$("#searchtermContract").val();` in the console?  Using dev-tools looks at the html as it was, the html won't show you the current value.

Comment: @freedom-m I have put a watch on $("#searchtermContract") and the value property is set to empty when the code is executed.

Comment: Use `$('#propertiesForContract').load(url, function() { $("#searchtermContract").val(""); });`

Comment: That worked Stephen Muecke. Make that the answer and I will give you a tick!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `jQuery.load()` is async so while its calling the server and returning the results, your `$("#searchtermContract").val("");` line of code has already run (it sets the value to `null` but then its overwritten by the results of the `load()` method. Instead change you code to

```
$('#propertiesForContract').load(url, function() {
   $("#searchtermContract").val("");
});
```

so that you set the value in the callback

Answer (score 1):

The jquery load() function is asynchronous in nature, meaning all codes below your call to load() will run immediately even though the load() is not finished yet. You may use the complete callback function of the load() jquery function so that your code in the callback will run once the load() function is completed. Do some reading on http://api.jquery.com/load/